# order <li> as I want in a list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI sortable elements. My jQuery script generate when user is checking some boxes. But I also have a select to allow the user to define the layout he wants.

And when he clicks on default in selector, I'd like to define the `<li>` order, or atleast I'd like them to come back as they were displayed for the first time in my page.

Do you have any solution for me ? (im using jQuery && jQuery UI)

Here is my code:

```js
$('#layout_choice').change(function(){
        window.layout_choice = $(this).val();

        //change li and ul id name
        $('#sortable > li').each(function(){
            let tmp_id = $(this).attr('id')
            tmp_id = tmp_id.replace(/([a-z]{3,8}\_\Bblock\B\_)[a-z]{4,7}/i, "$1" + window.layout_choice);
            $(this).attr('id', tmp_id);
        })
        //changing ul by replacing witg regex his class name
        let tmp_class_ul = $('#sortable').attr('class').split(' ')[2];
        $('#sortable').removeClass(tmp_class_ul)
        tmp_class_ul = tmp_class_ul.replace(/(\bsortable)(\_)?([a-z]{4,7})?/i, "$1" + "\_" + window.layout_choice);
        $('#sortable').addClass(tmp_class_ul);

        // disable sorting if user layout choice set on 'default'
        if(window.layout_choice == 'default')   $('#sortable').sortable('disable')
        else                                    $('#sortable').sortable('enable')

        if($(this).has('default')){
            // display them back with correct order.
        }
    })
```

```html
 <!--        Choice display manager-->
            <div class="col">
                <span class="badge badge-default">Choose the position of your selected elements</span>

                <select class="mt-1" id="layout_choice" name="layout_format">
                    <option selected disabled>--SELECT A LAYOUT TYPE--</option>
                    <option value="default">Default (non customizable)</option>
                    <option value="mini">Mini format customizable</option>
                    <option value="full">Full customizable</option>
                    <option value="" disabled>Customizable by lines</option>
                </select>


                <ul id="sortable" class="sortable_ul">
                    <!-- <li> for each category of information we will display in the builder -->
                </ul>

                <input class="d-none" type="text" id="categories_order" name="order">

            </div>
```

Any idea how I could do without remooving each and replacing each in the correct order. Thanks !

Comment: Hi, you can add data-attr to each li and specify number to them i.e : `1,2..` so whenever user click on default you can sort your lis using that values.

Comment: and then with the sort method that's it ? 
Will do a lot of lines because I'm generating `<li>` depending on their choice. I might do that if it is the only solution. ___________________________ **Can't I like, define a default state and then if they click on default option, bring back to that default state ?**

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example This example has no LI elements. Also what defines the original order?